# Objective-C, get string from text file?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsrange

I know there are a few different ways to find text in file, although I haven't found a way to return the text after the string I'm searching for. For example, if I was to search file.txt for the term `foo` and wanted to return `bar`, how would I do that without knowing it's `bar` or the length?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
if (!fileContentsString) {
    NSLog(@"Error reading file");
}

// Create the string to search for
NSString *search = @"foo";

// Search the file contents for the given string, put the results into an NSRange structure
NSRange result = [fileContentsString rangeOfString:search];

// -rangeOfString returns the location of the string NSRange.location or NSNotFound.
if (result.location == NSNotFound) {
    // foo not found. Bail.
    NSLog(@"foo not found in file");
    return;
}
// Continue processing
NSLog(@"foo found in file");    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [[NSString substringFromIndex:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/substringFromIndex%3a)

```
if (result.location == NSNotFound) 
{
    // foo not found. Bail.
    NSLog(@"foo not found in file");
    return;
}    
else    
{
    int startingPosition = result.location + result.length;
    NSString* foo = [fileContentsString substringFromIndex:startingPosition]        
    NSLog(@"found foo = %@",foo);  
}
```

Comment: thank you - i'll try this out. Is there any advantage/disadvantage from xingzhi.sg's example? just curious.

Comment: my solution is easier for that task (especially if you're not familiar with regex).
AND it just needs iOS 2.0 or OS X 10.0, so you don't need to carry an extra library with your project

Comment: `imageKey` must be iOS specific?; I'm try to create this for OS X, is there an equivalent for that?

Comment: sorry `imageKey` was a local variable in my project. i edited my answer it should be your local variable `fileContentsString`

Comment: okay, I understand. The problem now is that anything after `bar` is shown also. for example `foo bar is the string` will result in `bar is the string`. how do I only show `bar`?

Comment: search in the new string for first occurence of space and extract the first part. if there is no space, you already have your desired string.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/) and perform a regex look up:

```
NSArray * captures = [myFileString componentsMatchedByRegex:@"foo\\s+(\\w+)"];
NSString * wordAfterFoo = captures[1];
```

Not test though.

Comment: I get an error on `NSString * wordAfterFoo = captures[1];` -- Subscript requires size of interface `NSArray`, which is not constant in non-fragile ABI

Comment: oops... should be [captures objectAtIndex:1];